# How to filter data in report based on current date on JasperReports Server?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I've created a report in *iReport 5.0.1* and trying to figure out how to select records from today.  This will be a scheduled report to run at the end of the day without user intervention.  I've tried searching and not found anything yet.  I'm sure this is simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: It's related yo your data source. If you use mysql data to fill your report then create the corresponding mysql query. What's your data source?

Comment: @Eric Morrow You can read this post: [Filtering on a date range](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/filtering-date-range)

Comment: I have in the query in my where statement Report_Date = $P{Today}, but I get The document has no pages.  When I look at the data it should match.

Comment: Eric, see tomhelper's comment. You can build it into your query, but the syntax depends on your data source. What are you using as the data source?

Comment: We are using mysql.  Thanks for the insight so far.